# How to evaluate the performance of scenario generation algorithms?

Tags: stochastic-programming

I would like to compare the performance of various scenario generation algorithms.

What are the metrics for comparing the performance of these algorithms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a little research and found the paper that I have cited below. I think with 517 citations this paper and the reference therein can be a good source for you.

Paper:
Kaut, Michal, and Stein W. Wallace. "Evaluation of scenario-generation methods for stochastic programming." (2003).